# Enabling autoprefixing (specifically) grid for IE11 in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, postcss

I'm having a hard time getting grids to work with my Gatsby site. I'm using SASS via the `gatsby-plugin-sass` plugin and specifying options. Here's the exact config that I found online:

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    options: {
        postCssPlugins: [
            autoprefixer({
                grid: true
            }),
        ],
    },
}
```

That's placed in my gatbsy-config.js.

My .browserslistrc has the following:

```
last 2 version
> 1%
IE 10
```

Yet I'm still not getting the grids showing up properly.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Grid is disabled by autoprefixer by default.

Comment: @ksav as you can see above I've set grid to true.

Comment: Try adding this to the top of any scss file with grid declarations: `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */`

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that made a difference :(

Comment: You should be able to check if the ms prefixes are in your compiled css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use options, grid: true or grid: autoplace did not change a thing for me. 
/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */ at the begining of the .scss, or .module.scss works fine (like @ksav wrote)

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't make much of a difference for me.

Comment: Using the control comments will ONLY work in a local dev environment, they're stripped for production. See here for the only real hacky solution: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15509